# Random Variables: Show that conditional on the number of successes, all possibilities for the list of outcomes of the experiment are equally likely

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> A sequence of n independent experiments is performed. Each experiment
> is a success with probability p and a failure with probability q = 1 -
> p. Show that conditional on the number of successes, all possibilities
> for the list of outcomes of the experiment are equally likely (of
> course, we only consider lists of outcomes where the number of
> successes is consistent with the information being conditioned on).

I just learned about random variables and my thinking is: if we know there are k successes, we know there are $\binom{n}{k}$ different sequences of 1's and 0's such that there are k 1's. And these sequences are all equally likely by symmetry. Thus, given the number of successes, k, all possibilities for the list of outcomes of the experiment are equally likely.

But I know that's wrong because I didn't use any random variables.

So my main question is: what's wrong in my thinking (which involves no random variables)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your reasoning is that you do not know (or have not stated why you know) that the $\binom{n}{k}$ paths that are possible are equally likely given the condition that the total number of heads is $k$. This follows from the independence of the $X_i$, which your reasoning did not mention.

Comment: Does this work: each of the $\binom{n}{k}$ paths are equally likely because each trial is independent and each trial has the same probability for a success (p) and a failure (1-p).

Comment: It is true that each of the paths are equally likely because each trial is independent, but what you need to show is that they are equally likely **given** the number of heads.